# How do I declare a vector of pretermined length in a class?

Tags: c++, string

This is driving me around the bend. All the documentation on vectors is ridiculously deep.

In a class I want to declare a vector equal in length to the length of a string I've already declared. It sounds easy enough.

If I use:

```
class Test {
private:
    size_t size = 10;
    std::vector<int> array(size); 
};
```

I get "only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class"

If I:

```
std::vector<int> array(anarray.length());
```

I get the fantastically unhelpful:

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'anarray'

How do I do it?

Comment: Please show some more code to illustrate what you're trying to do. Specifically, elaborate on "declare a vector equal in length to the length of a string I've already declared".

Comment: Please provide the full code. What is `unarray`? Also you need to specify if you are using C++03 or C++11.

Comment: Also, `array` is a _bad_ name for your vector class member.

Comment: Yes, I accept that, it is for example, I'm not actually using it in my code.

Answer (score 3):

In-class initialization requires use of the `type var = value;` syntax or the uniform initialization syntax.

For your needs, it is more appropriate to use `type var = value;` syntax.

```
class Test {
  private:
    std::size_t size = 10;
    std::vector<int> array = std::vector<int>(size); 
};
```

You can initialize `size` using:

```
    std::size_t size{10};
```

However, if you use

```
    std::vector<int> array{size};
```

it will try to create a `std::vector` with one element containing the value of `size`. That's not what you are interested in.

Comment: '*In-class initialization requires use of the type var = value; syntax.*' Bullocks. It does not. Uniform initialization works perfectly well.

Comment: Apparently, I can't do that. This reads like a cut and paste from somewhere else and when I try it, as it says in the OP, it does not work. I get: only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class /  is not a type name, static, or enumerator / undeclared identifier. Therefore it must be incomplete at best?

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport, are you using a C++11 compiler? This syntax is not supported in prior versions of the language.

Comment: Do you know how I find out? I am, depressingly, limited to a University installation of Visual Studio. How do I find out which?

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport, I believe VS 2012 supports C++11. If you have VS 2010 or a prior version, you don't get support for C++11.

Comment: VS2012 doesn't support much of C++11. You have to use VS2013 to get serious C++11 support.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by bits and pieces scattered across comments to different answers, I figured out that OP does not use C++11 and does not need dynamic array capability. Because of that, my advice is to go with good ol' C-style static arrays. Following code would do the trick:

```
struct Test {
    static const size_t array_sz = 10;
    int my_array[array_sz];
};
```

If, by nature of being an assignment from moronic CS teacher, an `std::vector` is mandated, this is how it should be initialized:

```
struct Test {
    static const size_t array_sz = 10;
    std::vector<int> my_array;
    Test() : my_array(array_sz) {}
};
```

Explanation: `std::vector` needs to be **constructed** with a certain argument to specify it's size. Pre-C++11 the only way to call a specific constructor of a member variable was to do this in the so-called *initializer list* of the constructor of the enclosing class.

After C++11, this can also be done directly in site of member definition. But you need a compiler which is less than 6 years old for this.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, we haven't been mandated in either direction. It is true that I disagree with the teacher on a number of technical points though, but that's by the way. I started with the C static, wanted to do it all properly and it seems like I am defeated by the University installation. Thanks for reading though, this is v.helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Like this: (requires c++11 or better)

```
class Test {
private:
    size_t size = 10;
    std::vector<int> array = std::vector<int>(size);
};
```

Comment: Richard, that method throws up more errors than I already have:

only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class /
is not a type name, static, or enumerator /
undeclared identifier

Comment: Don't do it that way.

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport really? works fine on clang, c++14. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @RobK Why? This is fine.

Comment: An older one Richard. Foolishly, I didn't realise this uses an older dialect of C++ which means I might not be able to use the methods helpfully suggested with it. Right now it's looking like back pedal and use the old way no longer recommended ( frustrating ) or buy a new computer to get the go ahead ( at my own cost ).

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport compilers are free. It looks like you're on windows. Have a look at visual studio community edition 2015. on linux/osx there's gcc and clang. All free.

Comment: Yeah.... it's the PC. I thought I'd get through college without one. I don't want to throw a four figure sum away to get through college. The compiler we get for free. We get the full latest version. I just haven't got anything to run it on, in the name of keeping my budget down. But this university system is crippling.

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport to be honest, anything from microsoft is a horror show - requiring a more computing power than the energy output of the sun. you can install the latest gcc under cygwin, which requires almost no resources. instructions here. http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/ best of luck :-)

Comment: Thanks Richard, tbh, I would love to convert the whole thing to gcc or clang. Everything worked fine at home, it wasn't until I tried to compile under MSVC it all started to go wrong. It's only thanks to this discussion I have found MSVC broke because it doesn't really support the features I want to implement. This will compromise my final program, and probably earn me more points with the lecturer too. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `std::vector<int> array` and if you want you vector not be larger that one specific size create a method that check the vector size before insert.

Answer (score 0):

Data members are usually initialized in the member initialization list:

```
class Test
{
    std::vector<int> array;

public:

    Test() : array(10)
    {     // ^^^^^^^^^
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Just get rid of the `(size)`. The vector doesn't have, or have to have, a length until at least one instance of it exists. The number of elements in a vector is not part of its type. A `std::vector<int>` can contain no integers or a hundred integers -- it's still a `std::vector<int>`. When declaring that the vector is a member of the class, the number of members that instances of that vector will have, later when they exist, doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks David, that is helpful.

I've always used C arrays before, do you know of any easy routes into understanding vectors? They seem a lot more complicated!

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport - they're different from C arrays, but once you catch on, they're actually much simpler.

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport Basically, `std::vector` is a container for a dynamic variable-length array, which allocates its own memory.  When you try to store something in it, it'll check if it has room to hold more elements.  If it does, it'll just store it like normal.  If it doesn't, it'll automatically allocate more room.  It can look a bit daunting at first, but like a lot of things, it'll make a lot more sense once you have a little more experience with it.

Comment: There are scenarios where using a vector with the size specified during object construction is not only beneficial, but **crucial**.

Comment: Yes, but is this one of them? I notice David's post has been down-voted.  The array size is fixed and I know it in advance of compilation, it's length is constant and predetermined. So should I declare its length since it will never change size at run time?

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport, if you know the size during the compilation, you do not need vector at all. In C++11 (which you do not seem to be using) you'd use `std::array`, in older versions just use plain C-style static arrays.

Comment: Thanks, all this time I've been trying to find a way to do it properly, but you're right, I may not be able to jump that far ahead of the game with the C standard I'm using anyway. I started with the old style array, decided to look ahead, and now I think I'll have to backtrack. :-(

Comment: This note before I leave for the night is to thank everybody who commented on this post. Thanks for your help, I have learned much. Including the fact I can't really do what I'm trying to do on the system given to me by the University. :-(

Comment: It looks sergey as if that will have to be the answer for now. I'll have to save vector implementations until a future time when the university system can compile them. :-(